# How to setItem in localStorage within componentWillUnmount

Tags: reactjs, localstorage

In my searchBar component i record user input in this.state.value. While component unmounting, i must record this.state.value to localStorage, plus after reloading the tab localStorage value should be displayed in search bar. Hooks are not allowed. Im really stuck, please help to solve.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set your state default value from localStorage before render

```
this.setState(localStorage.getItem('your key'));
```

And when component unmounting set value to localStorage

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    localStorage.setItem('your key', this.state.value)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!